# UEFI Settings Missing

Tags: windows, operating-system, restart, bios, uefi

I am running WINDOWS 10 x64bit on ACER E5-521 AMD Processor

I need to turn on VT-x from UEFI Settings But I can not find it here. Is there any reason why it is like that on my machine?[Below is a link of a snapshot of my screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmDJY.jpg) Please check and help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, since you have an AMD processor, it's AMD-V that you'll need to activate.
Did you de-activate fast boot ? In the power settings.

Comment: No, I did not deactivate fast boot, How can I activate AMD-V